# Router disconnects me every day at the same time

Tags: networking, router

For some unknown to me reason my router disconnects me every day at almost the same exact time.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Router Log:

```
Jul 10 09:58:16 pppd[57]: LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)
Jul 10 09:58:16 PPPoE: Disconnected
Jul 10 09:58:19 pppd[57]: Connection terminated.
Jul 10 09:58:19 pppd[57]: Connect time 8163958.2 minutes.
Jul 10 09:58:19 pppd[57]: Sent 511397338 bytes, received 878379040 bytes.
Jul 10 09:58:49 pppd[57]: Starting link
Jul 10 09:58:49 pppd[57]: PPP session is 980
Jul 10 09:58:49 pppd[57]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Jul 10 09:58:52 pppd[57]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 10 09:58:52 pppd[57]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:4B:74:13 authorized
Jul 10 09:58:52 pppd[57]: Local IP address changed to XX.XX.148.218
Jul 10 09:58:53 PPPoE: connect to ISP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 11 09:58:53 pppd[57]: LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)
Jul 11 09:58:53 PPPoE: Disconnected
Jul 11 09:58:56 pppd[57]: Connection terminated.
Jul 11 09:58:56 pppd[57]: Connect time 1440.1 minutes.
Jul 11 09:58:56 pppd[57]: Sent 1813438109 bytes, received 3422917328 bytes.
Jul 11 09:59:16 ntp client: time is synchronized to time.nist.gov pool.ntp.org 
Jul 11 09:59:26 pppd[57]: Starting link
Jul 11 09:59:26 pppd[57]: PPP session is 886
Jul 11 09:59:26 pppd[57]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Jul 11 09:59:29 pppd[57]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 11 09:59:29 pppd[57]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:A1:1C:4A authorized
Jul 11 09:59:29 pppd[57]: Local IP address changed to XX.XX.207.124
Jul 11 09:59:29 pppd[57]: Remote IP address changed to XX.XX.246.30
Jul 11 09:59:29 PPPoE: connect to ISP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 12 09:59:29 pppd[57]: LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)
Jul 12 09:59:29 PPPoE: Disconnected
Jul 12 09:59:32 pppd[57]: Connection terminated.
Jul 12 09:59:32 pppd[57]: Connect time 1440.1 minutes.
Jul 12 09:59:32 pppd[57]: Sent 2362105148 bytes, received 2089980462 bytes.
Jul 12 09:59:36 ntp client: time is synchronized to time.nist.gov pool.ntp.org 
Jul 12 10:00:02 pppd[57]: Starting link
Jul 12 10:00:02 pppd[57]: PPP session is 495
Jul 12 10:00:02 pppd[57]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Jul 12 10:00:05 pppd[57]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 12 10:00:05 pppd[57]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:4B:74:13 authorized
Jul 12 10:00:05 pppd[57]: Local IP address changed to XX.XX.203.241
Jul 12 10:00:05 pppd[57]: Remote IP address changed to XX.XX.246.18
Jul 12 10:00:06 PPPoE: connect to ISP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 13 10:00:07 pppd[57]: LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)
Jul 13 10:00:07 PPPoE: Disconnected
Jul 13 10:00:10 pppd[57]: Connection terminated.
Jul 13 10:00:10 pppd[57]: Connect time 1440.1 minutes.
Jul 13 10:00:10 pppd[57]: Sent 2863355305 bytes, received 853862700 bytes.
Jul 13 10:00:40 pppd[57]: Starting link
Jul 13 10:00:40 pppd[57]: PPP session is 642
Jul 13 10:00:40 pppd[57]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Jul 13 10:00:43 pppd[57]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 13 10:00:43 pppd[57]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:C2:D9:B0 authorized
Jul 13 10:00:43 pppd[57]: Local IP address changed to XX.XX.204.134
Jul 13 10:00:43 pppd[57]: Remote IP address changed to XX.XX.246.21
Jul 13 10:00:43 PPPoE: connect to ISP
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jul 14 10:00:32 pppd[57]: LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)
Jul 14 10:00:32 PPPoE: Disconnected
Jul 14 10:00:35 pppd[57]: Connection terminated.
Jul 14 10:00:35 pppd[57]: Connect time 1439.9 minutes.
Jul 14 10:00:35 pppd[57]: Sent 3331721595 bytes, received 4171819205 bytes.
Jul 14 10:01:05 pppd[57]: Starting link
Jul 14 10:01:05 pppd[57]: PPP session is 1684
Jul 14 10:01:05 pppd[57]: Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0
Jul 14 10:01:08 pppd[57]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Jul 14 10:01:08 pppd[57]: peer from calling number XX:XX:XX:4B:74:13 authorized
Jul 14 10:01:08 pppd[57]: Local IP address changed to XX.XX.193.34
Jul 14 10:01:08 pppd[57]: Remote IP address changed to XX.XX.246.18
Jul 14 10:01:09 PPPoE: connect to ISP
```

Comment: Are you being disconnected from the router or the internet?

Comment: I was talking with the ISP earlier they said that there were no disconnections from their side. I cannot recall all computers at home being affected by this (but since the router disconnects I guess they are), because it happens quickly and there is not time to check, but it's a problem to me because I need a steady connection.

Comment: The log is from the router itself and it's a cable connection not wireless so placement is not important.

Comment: The line "LCP terminated by peer (Connect time expired)" makes me think that your configuration have some "session timeout". Can you check pppd configuration. The config may be ISP side (peer side) also.

Comment: If the origin of your "problem" is the router itself, check if your ISP disconnects clients periodically (where I live this happens randomly after more than 24 hours). My router for instance has got a *prevent forced disconnection* mode that when enabled disconnects the router at a set time every day and reconnects so you don't get disconnected randomly throughout the day.

Comment: I have not pppd settings set on my router, if they are set by the ISP I've no idea how to check them. @GiantTree I asked them a couple of times and they declined this being the case, however I have my reasons to believe that their customer support is simply not adequate to answer such queries and are flat out lying instead of saying - "I don't know".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that the connection gets terminated by the peer, as has been pointed out in the comments on your question, which implies that it is the ISP terminating the connection. Also, this happens precisely 24 hours after the connection has been established, which suggests a forced disconnection by your ISP (a measure to ensure your IP address changes every 24 hours, which makes running servers on your home network a bit more painful).

Try disconnecting or rebooting your router at a different time, and watch when the disconnections occur. If they now happen precisely 24 hours after the operation (rather than at the time you observed before), that is another indicator of your ISP disconnecting you every 24 hours.

Comment: The IPS technicians were just here and confirmed everybody's suspicions - the ISP is terminating the connection every 24 hours. The bad thing is that the first router in my chain is quite old and doesn't have scheduled restart so I'll have to wait until 3-4 AM to do a manual restart and keep the the disconnections going at that time of the night.